# Configure unique name per target in Prometheus Blackbox exporter

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

In Prometheus with blackbox exporter I have managed to configure 10+ URL for application availability, All of them are identified via their URL some of them are longer than the example shown below So Instead of display URL as an instance name how can I specify each with unique label.

For example

```
static_configs:
  - targets:
    - https://www.google.co.in/ # called as GoogleIndia
    - https://www.google.co.uk/ # called as GoogleUK
    - https://www.google.fr/    # called as GoogleFrance
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `metric_relabel_configs` to construct an `instance` (or completely new) label based on the instance name you specified, as described in [this blog post](https://medium.com/quiq-blog/prometheus-relabeling-tricks-6ae62c56cbda).

Or you can specify your targets like this, assigning them arbitrary labels in the process:

```
static_configs:
  - targets: ['https://www.google.co.in/']
    labels:
      name: `GoogleIndia`
  - targets: ['https://www.google.co.uk/']
    labels:
      name: `GoogleUK`
  - targets: ['https://www.google.fr/']
    labels:
      name: `GoogleFrance`
```

It's more verbose, but also easier to understand and more powerful.

Comment: how can I reference the arbitrary labels in the relabel_configs?

Comment: The values will automatically show up in the final labels. If you want to modify them, you can access them like this:

relabel_configs: [ { source_labels: [name], target_label: my_pretty_name } ]